# rake db:migrate fail. No terminal error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rake

I am working on the onemonthrails course.

I need to execute a migration using the below rake command. The devise migration file looks to be setup correctly.

```
   rake db:migrate
```

I am expecting to see some kind of confirmation like the following:

```
=======DeviseCreateUsers:  Migrating=======
create table (:users)
-> 0.0145s
add_index (:users :index  etc...
etc..
```

Instead, my terminal reverts straight back to the command line (with no errors) but nothing appears to have been done. For example:

```
Petes-Computer:example Pete$ rake db:migrate
Petes-Computer:example Pete$
```

The below error in my browser confirms it didn't work.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::RegistrationsController#new
Could not find table 'users'
```

There are a couple of other posts on this but no luck resolving. I am very new to ruby/rails/rake; please could someone advise.

Comment: Is the migration's timestamp (in the filename) greater than all the others?

Comment: Looks to be the time it was created rather than when i ran rake db:migrate if that helps

Comment: Assuming you don't have any existing data in your database, run rake db:reset. Make SURE you don't have any important data there.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense that the timestamp of the migration is when the migration was created. That's the core aspect of a migration. If you had multiple migrations in db/migrate and this migration's timestamp was before one of the others, it would make sense that there would be nothing to migrate.

Comment: nothing in there, just created it as part of an exercise; rake db:reset seemed successful: -- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0094s

Comment: And you verified that the table exists?

Comment: How do I do that? :) sorry only DB experience is using mySql through a phpMyAdmin. Somewhere within my migrate folder? i see a development.sqlite3 file, schema.rb, seeds.rb, test.sqlite3

Comment: You can just look at your schema.rb file. That gets updated every migration.

Comment: Thanks. No, doesn't seem to exist. Schema is just: 
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do
end

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51554/discussion-between-jakethesnake-and-pete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our discussion, it turns out Pete's migration file didn't have an extension. `rake db:migrate` didn't pick up the migration because it wasn't an .rb file.